# Transforming web.config Transform files across environments and projects

Tags: c#, powershell, web-config, app-config, web.config-transform

So here is my dilemma. I have a web.config file. I have FIFTEEN transform files, once for each environment (Lab1, Lab2, etc., Alpha, Beta, Prod, etc.). Now multiply that by 30 projects.

Rather than trying to maintain 15 transform files across 30 projects I would like:

parse each transform file.
For each Environment/Configuration/Setting, store this data from the parsed file in a database.
Create a "master" transform file that is a merge of all the environment-specific transform files (assuming that web.release.config will have a majority of the transforms)
Allow a user to run my c# program that accesses the database and based on the desired environment, takes the master transform file and replaces all the settings (ie "value") with the environment/configuration specific values from the DB.

What I currently have:
a c# program that stores the env/config/setting in a DB. It can create and update.
a powershell program that calls the above to set or get a set of env/config/setting.

what I need:
A way to parse the transform file, identify each transform call, and store the env/config/setting value in the DB.

Then
the best way to "merge" the 15 transform config files into a master transform file, making sure there is no duplication and clearly notating the values that need to be replaced. I was thinking that using square brackets - which are not used anyplace else in a config file, is a great way to do this:

add key="LabName" value=[[REPLACE ME]]

transforms for the production environment into

add key="LabName" value="Prod"

thanks in advance.

Comment: This reads a lot like a SOW (statement of work).  Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: Parse the transform file and identify and stores all the env/config/setting values, merge all 15 config files into one and parameterize all values that need to be replaced. No SOW - this is just an idea I had to make my life easier,